# fuel cms simple module CSRF update issue

Tags: iframe, fuelcms

When I enable the CSRF protection at Fuel 1.4,i am getting an csrf token reset issue .

**lest elaborate the issue** :

my **config.php** in application config

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 's_csrf_tocken';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 's_csrf_cookie';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

in a simple module with following filds

**name,profile_image ....**

so when ever i am going to create or edit then upload a file in profile image section then return back in main from page of the module .

and try to save the from it is giving the error:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> The action you have requested is not allowed.

as the csrf token got changed in iframe of the asset up loader and in main from the csrf not getting updated .

any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have implemented a solution i cant shay its very proper . it still have scope to improve .
i used a controller to fetch the csrf

```
class Csrf_secure extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('user_agent');
    }
    function get_csrf()
    {
        $this->fuel->admin->check_login();
        if(false)
        {}
        elseif(trim($this->agent->referrer()) =='' or $this->input->is_ajax_request()== false)
        {show_404(); }
        else {
            echo json_encode(array(
            'token'=>$this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
            'hash'=>$this->security->get_csrf_hash()
                ));
        } }}
```

fetching and updating the function when ever a modal i frame is closed
from (needed to optimized if it can be celled only if an update is occurred on the from  )

> /fuel/modules/fuel/assets/js/jquery/plugins/jqModal.js

altering the

> $.fn.jqmHide

function  as follow .

```
$.fn.jqmHide=function(t){return this.each(function(){
        $.jqm.close(this._jqm,t);
        if(typeof window.parent != "undefined" ){
            if(typeof window.parent.CallParent == "undefined" ){
                window.parent.CallParent = function(context)
                {
                    $.getJSON(jqx_config.basePath+"csrf_secure/get_csrf", function(result){
                        if(typeof result.token  != "undefined"){
                                document.querySelectorAll('#'+result.token).forEach(function(rf){
                                    rf.value=result.hash;
                                });
                          }
                    });
                };
            };
            window.parent.CallParent(this._jqm,t); 

        }

    });};
```